<<<< org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: SyntaxError: Unnamed:1:5 Expected ; but found Sum Mock Sum of numbers from 1 to n
I am using karate frame work (java8 and karate1.3.1) and I need to  create a mock service with  karate's feature files .
this is small part of my scenarios.( I have same error  for all scenarios in my file) and it gave weird warning.
17:52:36.492 [armeria-common-worker-nio-2-1] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetectorFactory - Loaded default ResourceLeakDetector: io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector@19037a8b
17:52:36.673 [armeria-common-worker-nio-2-2] WARN com.intuit.karate - scenario match evaluation failed at line 9: Mock Addition - **com.intuit.karate.KarateException: js failed:




01: Mock Addition
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: SyntaxError: Unnamed:1:5 Expected ; but found Addition
Mock Addition
^**

org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.eval(Context.java:425)
com.intuit.karate.graal.JsEngine.evalForValue(JsEngine.java:139)
com.intuit.karate.graal.JsEngine.eval(JsEngine.java:135)
com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.evalJs(ScenarioEngine.java:1190)
com.intuit.karate.core.MockHandler.isMatchingScenario(MockHandler.java:274)
com.intuit.karate.core.MockHandler.handle(MockHandler.java:175)
com.intuit.karate.http.HttpServerHandler.lambda$serve$0(HttpServerHandler.java:59)

17:52:36.673 [armeria-common-worker-nio-2-2] WARN com.intuit.karate.core.MockHandler - no scenarios matched, returning 404: POST /api/add
I also debugged framework code . this is the place which I got exception
enter image description here
Feature: Mock API for Calculator

  Background:
    * def response = {}
    * def userInfo = { user: 'info' }
    Given url 'http://localhost:8083/api/'

  Scenario: Mock Addition
    Given path 'add'
    And method POST
    And def params = karate.jsonPath(request, '$.params')
    Then match params == [1, 2]
    And def result = params[0] + params[1]
    And def response = { result: '#(result)', user: '#(userInfo.user)' }




I think the only way to resolve this is to follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - of course if you can identify any bug in the framework and submit a PR that would be ideal
